# Restarting network manager hangs system

Tags: networking, 16.04, kde, crash

Note: It seems it wasn't any error of the network manager. As it turns out the error occures due to the kernel. Upon logging off and back on the system hangs. When I have tried updating the kernel it broke everything so I just disable hibernation until the OS gets updated. Thank you for all the replies.

In Ubuntu 16.04 every time my PC goes to sleep it causes the network manager to disconnect. After searching around I found that restarting the network manager service should fix the issue, but when I attempt it, another popped up. The internet reconnects but after a minute the entire system hangs until force rebooted. I have tried using KDE Neon to see if fixed the issue but it remains. This has not been fixed on either of them as I tested it yesterday.

Comment: Have you installed wicd? It conflicts with network-manager

Comment: kenn. No I have not. The error occured right after installation at both times. Even without any packages installed it still occured

Comment: One imagines you should disable sleep until you fix this. Check /var/log/syslog for the times while going to sleep, while waking from sleep, and while frozen for clues.

Comment: what is the output of `pgrep -oaf dhcp*`

Comment: Kenn 1223 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlp3s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-272aca64-2e52-48a8-a40e-d2ec0e1f4cb7-wlp3s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp3s0.conf wlp3s0